# Convolution of two uniform r.v

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution

I have a problem with that exercise: 
We have ∼Unif[0,1] and Y∼Unif[3,5].The random variables X,Y are independent. We define a random variable Z=X+Y and I want to find the PDF of Z using the convolution.
Here is my result:

[image]
Is it right?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895075/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables) is the answer to a very similar question.

Comment: Yes, it is right.