# Limits of integration on the convolution of two uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are iid's uniform distributions on [0,1]. Then $Z=X+Y$.

Reading through other similar questions such as [density of sum of two uniform random variables $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), I'm still struggling to understand how exactly the interval $0<z<2$ is reached.

It seems to me just to start this problem it is necessary to define the interval of $z$. I assume that if $X$ and $Y$ can only take on values from $[0,1]$, then at most $z$ can be $2$. Is this the correct way to think about this? More specifically I'm referring to the need of two cases, $0<z<1$ and $1<z<2$, and how they are obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables can each be between $0$ and $1$, so the smallest the sum can be is $0$ and the largest the sum can be is $2$.

As for the actual distribution, the reason for why the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of the distributions is because:
$$ P(Z = z) = \sum_x P(X = x) \cdot P(Y = z - x) $$
where the sum is taken over all possible values of $x$. When it comes to continuous random variable, we must use the probability density function, and so:
$$f_Z(z)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) \, dx $$
This integral is the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$.

In the case of these two distributions in this specific problem, the convolution looks like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#/media/File:Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself2.gif

This section explaining the visual interpretation may help as well:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation