# Sum of "n" independent random variables.

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim U_{[0,1]}$.

$X_1,..,X_n$ are independent. Let us define : $Y=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$
How to find the PDF of $Y$?

Comment: Here is the answer for $n=2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1

Comment: This is known as the Irwin-Hall distribution:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution.