# Area of the region $\{(x,y):0\leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y\leq 1, 3/4\leq x+y\leq 3/2\}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, area

> Find the area of the region $\{(x,y):0\leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y\leq 1, 3/4\leq x+y\leq 3/2\}$ (using definite integration).

I cannot understand how to find this area. I have graphed the lines and found out the required region. I found the definite integral $\int_{0}^{1} (3/2-y)-(3/4-y)dy$ but it is yielding an extra areas. How do I find the area of the region?

Comment: **HINT:** Find the area of the unit square (easy). Then find the area enclosed by the axes and $x+y=\frac34$. Lastly find the area enclosed by $x=1$, $y=1$ and $x+y=\frac32$ and perform the appropriate subtraction. In this case it may be easier to do it without integration as the areas are simple geometric shapes.

Comment: @Cuoredicervo I just edited the post... I'll delete my comments to reduce the noise.

Comment: This is the same as the probability $P(3/4<X+Y<3/2)$ where $X,Y$ are independent uniform variables on $(0,1)$. So from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1) post, the area is $\int_{3/4}^1 z\,dz+\int_1^{3/2}(2-z)\,dz=\frac{19}{32}$.

Comment: To clarify, you can find the area/probability from a picture alone (without integration).

Answer (score 1):

Since $y \leq 1$, it is :

$$\frac{3}{4} \leq x + y \leq \frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

But $x \geq 0$, thus :

$$0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Then, for $y$ one would get :

$$\frac{1}{4} \leq y \leq 1$$

The desired area of $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x \geq 1, y \leq 1, \frac{3}{4} \leq x+y \leq \frac{3}{2}\}$, is :

$$A(D) = \iint_D \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^1\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

Answer (score 1):

We should be able to find the area of this polygon without calculus.

[image]

At the very least, you should be able to divide it up into a bunch of triangles.

by the shoelace algorithm I get:

$\begin {array}{}
\frac 34 & 0\\
1&0\\
1&\frac 12\\
\frac 12& 1\\
0&1\\
0&\frac 34 \end{array}$

$\frac 12( \frac 12 + 1 + \frac 12 - \frac 14 - \frac 9{16}) = \frac {19}{32}$

If you want to use calculus, most direct would be

$\int_0^{\frac 12} 1 - (\frac 34 - x) \ dx + \int_{\frac 12}^{\frac 34} (3/2 - x) - (\frac 34 - x) \ dx +  \int_{\frac 34}^1 3/2 - x \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using the symmetry of given construction,
we can consider it in a coordinate system, rotated by $45^\circ$

[image]

Then

\begin{align}
[ABECDF]&=
2\left(
\int_{\tfrac{3\sqrt2}8}^{\tfrac{\sqrt2}2}  x\,dx 
+\int_{\tfrac{\sqrt2}2}^{\tfrac{3\sqrt2}4} (\sqrt2-x) \, dx
\right)
=\frac{19}{32}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, the region is a square with two isosceles right-angles triangles cut off, making its area$$1-\tfrac12\left(\left(\tfrac12\right)^2+\left(\tfrac34\right)^2\right)=1-\tfrac12\cdot\tfrac{13}{16}=\tfrac{19}{32}.$$