# Wikipedia: mistake in triangular distribution?

Tags: uniform-distribution

I'm referring to the article on [Triangular Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), under the sub-heading: *Distribution of the sum of two standard uniform variables*.

Surely the maximum of sum of two uniform random numbers is not $1$. So $b$ needs to be $2$ and $c$ needs to be $1$ in the article. Am I missing something? I came across that article while writing [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1/3540035#3540035) to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1) question, which has the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki page currently defines $X = \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$ where $X_1,X_2$ are uniform on $[0,1]$, so $X$ is the mean, not the sum.

Maybe you're just arguing against the title of that subsection?  It's entirely possible that it's a result of wikipedia having multiple authors.

Comment: So should the correct title for that calculation be - "Distribution of the MEAN of two standard uniform variables"?

Comment: It would arguably be more appropriate, yes.  I don't know if I'd go as far as stating whether it's "correct".  Scalar multiples are, after all, effectively equivalent except possibly in limiting cases.

Comment: Thanks, I just created a new account and submitted the edit. Lets see what the wiki mods say.

Comment: @Innocent: There are no mods at Wikipedia. Wikipedia is edited collectively by all editors (now including you – welcome! :-). Your edit is fine; I'm sure it will stay. There was actually a previous incarnation of this section heading that said "mean"; it was changed to "Symmetric triangular distribution" in [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Triangular_distribution&diff=724622103&oldid=702790338), and later reintroduced as a sub-heading in [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Triangular_distribution&diff=787953514&oldid=785854726), now with "sum".

Comment: @joriki Thanks, I didnt know that, I somehow thought they followed same system as math.stackexchange.