# convolution for uniform distribution with variable borders

Tags: probability-distributions

I need to calcuate a convolution of two uniform distributed random variables, both are defined as $f_z\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{h},z\in\left(0,h\right)$, to get the pdf for Z.

As a convolution of two continious random variables is defined $fz\left(z\right)=\int fx\left(z-y\right)fy\left(y\right)dy$ hence z = x + y, so x = z-y.

Based on [this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-independent-uniform-random-variables-on-0-1/357842#357842) my current idea for the integrand and the borders are:

$\int_{0}^{z}{\frac{1}{2h}dz}\ for\ 0\le\ z\ \le\ h $

and

$\int_{z-h}^{h}{\frac{1}{2h}dz}\ for\ z-h\le\ z\ \le\ 2h$

Which leads to a triangular function like

$
fz(z) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2h} \text{for 0 < z < h} \text{ and }
1 - \frac{1}{2h} \text{for z-h < z < 2h}
\end{cases}$

Is that correct ?

Comment: Where does $2h$ come from?

Comment: Which 2h do you mean ? 
2h in the integrand comes from fx * fy = 1/h * 1/h.
For the border, as far as i understood the example, i have to add up the borders of both function in my case h+h, but guide me if that is a wrong assumption.

Comment: $(\frac 1 h)(\frac 1 h)=(\frac 1 {h^{2}})$

Comment: Oh sure, so it's
$fz(z) = \frac{z}{h²}$ for 0<z<h and
$fz(z) = \frac{2*h-z}{h²}$ for z-h<z<2*h,
 right ?

Comment: Can someone confirm ?